# Calculate C and R in a CMOS Crystal Oscillator

Tags: clock, crystal, clock-speed

I stumbled over this simple solution to drive a crystal oscillator, but I need to connect a 25.17MHz crystal instead of the 10MHz in this schematic. How do I calculate R1 and C for a given frequency f(max)?
If C is taken from the crystal's datasheet, how do I calculate R1 then?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiZgVX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm going to use this as a VGA pixel clock driving a couple of counters. If anyone has an even simpler solution, it's mostly welcome.

Comment: Check this document out: https://www.crystek.com/documents/appnotes/pierce-gateintroduction.pdf

Comment: Note that both NOT gates are not Schmitt triggers.

Comment: As a rough guide, the resistance of R1  needs to be about equal to the reactance of C at the crystal frequency.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to buy a [ECS-100A-251.7](https://ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ecs_100.pdf) 25.175 MHz oscillator, if that's close enough for you.

R1 has to do with limiting the drive power to the crystal. C is *calculated* from the load capacitance on the crystal datasheet and the input+ stray capacitance- twice the load capacitance minus the input+stray capacitance.

You could also buy a pre-programmed programmable oscillator such as the [SIT2018BE-S1-18E-25.166000G](https://www.sitime.com/datasheet/SiT2018) which is a Digikey value-added item and available in 25.166 MHz. Also available in 25.175MHz as SIT8008BI-13-18E-25.175000G.

I would *not* suggest using this circuit- oscillators made with Schmitt triggers are notoriously unpleasant. It should only be attempted with an **unbuffered** inverter in the oscillator position.

Comment: 25.175 MHz would be exactly the correct frequency for VGA pixel clock.

Comment: I once took advantage of a 'feature' of a particular series of logic (74LCX04) to make a very reliable oscillator. The part had significant ground bounce due to lead inductance so it always started up correctly.

Comment: @PeterSmith That part has a really complex internal circuit. I guess the EMI suppression circuitry also suppresses  VHF/UHF oscillation that can occur sporadically with buffered inverters. The classic solution is to use the 74HCU04, of course, but if the transconductance isn't high enough (typical graph only is supplied) it might not start (low temperature and low supply voltage would be worst-case for a given unit).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I seem to recall that the classic unbuffered inverter was the CD4049UB but it was of course somewhat limited in frequency range. I needed 20.48MHz in my particular application (in 1995).